# Recall javascript on click in tumblr

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've added the facebook like button on my tumblr page. But each time I click on the "load more" button, the facebook button doesn't appear on the next articles. I think I have to recall the facebook script at this moment to make it work. But i don't know how.

Here is the facebook script I have in my body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And here is the part of the footer where I have to load the rest of the post on my page (I think…):

```
<footer{block:PermalinkPage} class="individual-footer"{/block:PermalinkPage}>

    {block:IndexPage}
    {block:IfLoadMoreLink}
    <div class="load-more">
        {block:IfLoadMoreText}{text:Load More Text}{block:IfLoadMoreText}
    </div>
    {/block:IfLoadMoreLink}
    <a href="#top" class="scroll-top">&#9650;</a>
    {/block:IndexPage}
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: And Where's your "Like" button?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/